# Kubuntu stylus pen mode for Panasonic touchpad problem

Tags: drivers, 20.04, touchscreen, stylus

The Panasonic FZ-M1 offers an input mode by finger or stylus pen.
Has anyone been able to activate the stylus mode on a Intel core m5-6y57 in Ubuntu?

I was able to use the stylus pen mode on FZ-M1 devices with processors m5-4302U or N2807. But had no luck with the model with this special m5-6y57 processor.

system

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.8
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-56-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 4 × Intel® Core™ m5-6Y57 CPU @ 1.10GHz
Memory: 7,7 GiB
```

xinput list

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Sharp Corp.   07EA0004                    id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB FHD Webcam: USB FHD Webcam            id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 Camera: USB2.0 Camera              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel Virtual Buttons                     id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Panasonic Laptop Support                  id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

xinput-choices

```
$ xinput list-props 9
Device 'Sharp Corp.   07EA0004':
        Device Enabled (157):   1
        Coordinate Transformation Matrix (159): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
0.000000, 1.000000
        libinput Calibration Matrix (297):      1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
0.000000, 1.000000
        libinput Calibration Matrix Default (298):      1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.
000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        libinput Send Events Modes Available (280):     1, 0
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (281):        0, 0
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (282):        0, 0
        Device Node (283):      "/dev/input/event8"
        Device Product ID (284):        1245, 38754
```

and

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 5986:0656 Acer, Inc  
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 13d3:5224 IMC Networks  
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04dd:9762 Sharp Corp.  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:2514 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp.  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I've been trying to get the pen stylus to work for four weeks without success.
There is no option in the Bios. The pen stylus is passive with a small tip.

Thank you for any help.